# How to represent mathematical function in Markdown

Tags: intellij-idea, markdown

Given a formula presentation as depicted in the image

[image]

May I know, how we can render this kind of presentation in Markdown.

I am using the IntelJ Jupyter Notebook for this.

Post Edit

Image rendering as suggested by Lonnie, using the following command
$$
u[n] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \delta[n-k]
$$

[image]

Comment: It is not yet supported in IntelliJ IDEA. Feel free to upvote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-213075

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LaTeX to represent the formula. I use ObsidianMD and there are a couple options.

- Single dollar signs for inline formulas
- Double dollar signs for
  block formulas

For the formula you're trying to write, you could use the following LaTeX with the dollar sign formatting if you're in ObsidianMD.

$$\zeta[n] = \begin{cases}
1 & \text n = 0 \
0 &n \neq 0
\end{cases}$$

Depending on what editor you're using, I think you can also use [MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) formatting for the LaTex. This, in some cases, just means you're formatting the function using [] but it depends on the editor.

Hope this helps.

---

I see, I just had another look at your original post; overlooked the editor you were using. It seems like you're trying to get the equation to render in display mode in your notebook. Maybe try surrounding the equation in [] notation. I know this works in a flashcard app that uses MathJax to render LaTeX called Anki.

Give the below a try:

```
\[
```

\zeta[n] = \begin{cases}
1 & \text n = 0 \
0 &n \neq 0
\end{cases}
]

Or maybe this

```
\(
```

\zeta[n] = \begin{cases}
1 & \text n = 0 \
0 &n \neq 0
\end{cases}
)

That's my best guess, hope this works.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the render is not as expected as per the image. For completeness, I attach the image in the OP

Comment: I see, I just had another look at your original post; overlooked the editor you were using.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately, it still does not render properly